# Burnside group,particular example,reference

Tags: group-theory

What is the first example of $B(m,n)$ which is infinite?
Here $m$ is the number of generators and $B(m,n)$ is the Burnside group
of order $n$ (but not finite). Something like e.g. $B(3,7)$ will be ok.
A reference with a simple proof of infiniteness is of interest.

Comment: You need to say what you mean by "the first example", but the answer is not known. The first candidate is $B(2,5)$. There are no simple proofs of infiniteness for any groups $B(m,n)$ - the proofs are very long, technical and difficult! Adian proved that $B(2,n)$ is infinite for odd $n > 665$, so the first example that has been proved infinite might be $B(2,667)$.

Comment: By "the first example" I do not mean anything technical. I would like to se a proof,as simple as possible, be it 2 or 3 pages in a book,that a concerte $B(m,n)$ is not finite. I do not insist on the very first example.So even $B(32,10)$ will be ok for my purpose.

Comment: There is no such proof! The proofs are more like 200 pages, and extremely difficult. I expect only a handful of people have ever read and understood them.

Comment: I see.Are you one of them? Is such a proof available online in pdf?

Comment: I have said already  that the smallest $n$ for which it has been proved is odd $n > 665$ (unless this has been improved very recently, but I would expect to have heard about it because it would be hot news!) No I am afraid that I am not one of the select few who have read the proofs! Try the wikipedia page on the Burnside Problem for more information.

Comment: More like 200 pages will be a rigorous proof.Is there some explanation of the proof technique and main ideas for common sense to grasp it?

Comment: Take a look at http://kgs.logic.at/files/Adian-Abstract.pdf -- also http://rcoulon.perso.math.cnrs.fr/papiers/notes.pdf may be interesting (long, but more details).

Comment: So, is your question really "What is the simplest proof that some $B(m,n)$ is infinite?" and want a reference? I am guessing the easiest proofs around will rely heavily on some sort of (generalized) small cancellation theory. Have you looked at the wiki page for Burnside's problem? Basically your question is not clear, you ask for the first example (whatever that means) but in the comments you said you don't care.